# ModalInstance updating Image from upload

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to upload an image from a drag and drop feature. I have set the modal and my drag and drop feature fine, but what I am having an issue is when I upload the file I would like to update the img src. I have a simplified version for my controller.

```
app.controller("CreateUploadInstanceCtrl", ["$scope", "$uibModalInstance",
function ($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

    this.image = "/path";
}]);
```

In my modal call I have the following:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/views/forms/upload_profile_picture.html',
            controller: 'CreateUploadInstanceCtrl',
            }
        });
```

In my Html I would assume that I could just call 
`<img ng-src="{{image}}"/>` to get the image to show on upload but I see nothing firing. I am not sure how the this.image can be translated to the html side since I can't load a controller into the html view. Would I need a resolve and if so how would I use the resolve?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this.image, try using $scope.image and in html specify ng-controller="CreateUploadInstanceCtrl"